# Using Maven with JBoss soa platform

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, m2eclipse

We have a jboss soa platform license and want to start using Maven for our projects and services. We started working on samples and were able to create simple multi module projects successfully. But I see that every time Maven connects to a central repo and my understanding from the docs is that the dependent jars are by default downloaded to the .m2/repository. But, the problem is we want our projects to use the jars that comes with our jboss soa platform. I see the Maven website page that shows how to add 3rd party jars, but adding all the jars that comes with a distribution would be time consuming and cumbersome.(especially finding the groupId and artifactIds for every single one of them) 1.) Is there an easy way to do this? 2.) I think we still have to go to the Maven central repo to get all other plugins(like maven-war-plugin, jar-plugin etc..), right?(because our JBoss platform doesn't come with those).

Appreciate the suggestions. It will help us greatly in starting off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert on Maven but this should be possible by using the `scope` and set it to `provided`. 
See the [Maven Doc on the scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) for more info. 
It is meant to indicate that the dependency is provided by a container.